# Why LibGdx texturepacker doesn't pack images in order?

Tags: libgdx, texturepacker

I got these [images](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2A-MsJCpOP6SjEyM0g2VGZxRVk) and when I pack them they come in the wrong order, like the last 7 images or so go to the front and this messes it all up for me and I don't even know why.I have packed images before with no problems.

Comment: Why does the order matter? The order is completely arbitrary because the packer is attempting to optimize the size of the packer image. How are you retrieving the images?

Comment: Im retrieving them by this  `batch2.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, false), -6.3f, -5.1f, 2f, 3f);`     with a timer starting

Comment: I mean how are you retrieving the texture regions from the atlas.

Comment: I create an  `animation = new Animation(1/15f,textureAtlas.getRegions());`

Comment: and the  textureAtlas is just  `textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas("personanimation.pack");`

Comment: If you suffix your sequence with `_01`, `_02` etc... you can just load that into the animation and it will have a proper sequence. It will use index in the atlas. It even gets rid of duplicates in case you rendered a duplicated frame.

Answer (score 2):

TexturePacker does not store regions in a certain order unless you specify that order using indices appended to the file names. The intended way to pack and retrieve an animation is as follows:

**1)** Name the source images with their frame numbers appended, for example:

```
run1.png, run2.png, run3.png, etc.
```

**2)** Pack them with TexturePacker.

**3)** After loading the TextureAtlas, retrieve a set of regions by name. For example:

```
animation = new Animation(1/15f, textureAtlas.findRegions("run"));
```

The retrieved regions will be in the order of the frame numbers that were in the source file names.

Comment: I got all the images excactly the way you posted: vn1.png, vn2.png... ,but when I look at my textureAtlas pack it begins like vn7,vn8,vn9,vn10,vn6,vn3,vn4,vn5  :/

Comment: Have you modified the texture packer default settings? There is one called useIndices which should remain true. Or maybe I am remembering wrong and you also need an underscore before those numbers in the file names.

Comment: I can not see any use indices, or do you mean use aliases?I have tried a lot of different settings, but still nothing. I had put a link in my post where the images are that I want to pack.

Comment: Looks like it's spelled `useIndexes` --I was going by memory. :) The instructions for properly using TexturePacker are in the documentation: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer Which TexturePacker are you using, by the way? The reason I ask is I'm now remembering that people occasionally ask questions on here and their problems have to do with them using TexturePacker-gui, which is based on a very outdated TexturePacker.

Comment: But it does not matter in what order they are in the texture pack??? As long as the animation is good right?